# How to send a formatted mail for webform submission?

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, email, receipts

I have created a Unpaid event and connected to the webform. Although online registration is enabled and email option is ticked, I was not able to send a formatted email.

I am able to send email using the webform email settings submissions.

Is there a workaround? Thanks

Comment: I’ve added to John’s response below; that would be the way I would go about it as well. It’s also possible to install/configure Drupal HTML mail modules - but it’s more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) for this.

Additional info:
Consider setting a small delay (when you configure your CiviRule) to ensure all CiviCRM data are saved before you Email your message out.

PS in additional to CivRules - you will also need to add the Extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api

Comment: Thanks both of you. How can I include the webform components in the email?

Comment: @Tapash could you be more specific about the webform components you want to include?

Comment: I mean whatever field/content the person fills on the Webform, I would like to include them in them in the email like a receipt just to summarise what information they have provided and about the event. Hope this makes sense. @JonG-MegaphoneTech

Comment: Edit: I need mixture of submission values of webform & civicrm that can be sent via the email using civirules.

Comment: are you storing the submitted values in civicrm as well, or only in the webform?